# bootstrap hero-unit height - Leaflet

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I have a basic bootstrap layout with a navbar and a sidebar(span 3) + map(span 9).
My problem is that when i look at this code in the browser the map looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15923835/bootstr.jpg

But I want a fixed size for the map (it should cover 80% of the page something. I have tried to set a fixed height in every DIV but nothing happens. Do you have any suggestions?

Sorry for my bad technical explanation (i'm trying to learn)

here's a copy of the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
    <div class="span9">

        <div class="hero-unit" id="map"></div>

            <script src="../leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>           
            <script>

                var map = new L.Map('map');

                var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',

                    cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',

                    cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});

                map.setView(new L.LatLng(55.367, 10.811), 6).addLayer(cloudmade);

        var trailers = new L.LayerGroup();

        <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT tblmain.modemid, max(dateepoch), tblmain.date, tblmain.speed, tblmain.la, tblmain.lo, tblmain.t1, tblmain.t2, tblmain.spt1, tblmain.spt2, tbltrailers.name \n"
            . "FROM tblmain\n"
            . "LEFT JOIN tbltrailers\n"
            . "on tblmain.modemid = tbltrailers.modemid\n"
            . "GROUP BY modemid ");
         $i = 1;
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $modemid=$row['modemid'];
         $trailernummer=$row['name'];
         $date=$row['date'];
         $lat=$row['la'];
         $lon=$row['lo'];
         $speed=$row['speed'];
         $t1=$row['t1'];
         $t2=$row['t2'];
         $spt1=$row['spt1'];
         $spt2=$row['spt2'];
         echo ("var marker$i = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng($lat, $lon));
         marker$i.title = \"test\";
         marker$i.bindPopup(\"<h1>$trailernummer</h1><br/>Modemid: $modemid<br/>Datum: $date<br/>Temp 1: $t1<br/>Temp 2: $t2<br/>Setpoint 1: $spt1<br/>Setpoint 2: $spt2 <br/> \").openPopup();
        trailers.addLayer(marker$i);
         "); 
         $i++;
         }
         ?> 
                map.addLayer(trailers);


                //marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

            </script>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as specified in the quick start : http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/quick-start.html use a style on the div#map

```
<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: the hero unit should normally dont mixup but in case, try <div class="hero-unit"><div id="map" style="height:200px;"></div></div>

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that answer! It, off course, worked perfect!

Two additional questions:

1: Is there any way to always put the height of the map as high as possible depending on the users resolution?

2: is there a way to get theese nice rounded edges also on the map as in the rest of the application? Looks a little bit boring now

Comment: 1- there is no such native tweaks in both bootstrap & leaflet you need to rely on javascript do set the map height for eg 25% of the page height. I did not remember a good pointer, but with http://api.jquery.com/height/ you could set the height as 25% of the body height.  2- no tricks , just css , add -webkit-border-radius: 6px;-moz-border-radius: 6px;border-radius: 6px; within a custom css file or directly add these to the style attribute : style="height: 200px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;-moz-border-radius: 6px;border-radius: 6px;